# Add your Lanyrd conferences to your CV on careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, jobs, cv

I think it would be cool if you could add the conferences that you've attended to your CV.

[Here](http://lanyrd.com/services/badges/docs/) are the docs for how to add this info from lanyrd to your site

Comment: Definitely want to add my conferences. What's the thought on this?

Comment: I would like to be able to add speaking history to Careers.SO, however I don't want to import from just Lanyrd. I'd like to be able to include a slideshow link with image, a video, a description of the talk, and a link to the conference site. This could probably be part of the Writing section.