# Link to speaking engagements at conferences

Tags: feature-request, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add your Lanyrd conferences to your CV on careers.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95066/add-your-lanyrd-conferences-to-your-cv-on-careers-stackoverflow-com)

The title says it all: Either allow linking to Lanyrd or let me manually add speaking engagements in my Stackoverflow Careers profile.